# Navigation button on mobile view is collapsing immediately after opening

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress website with mystile theme.
I am facing this problem in mobile responsive view that the navigation button collapses immediately after expanding.

I have tried every possible thing. even reinstalled the theme in the server still no luck.

Please help as i cannot promote my website mobile version.

Somehow I manged to google the same issue but not for mystile, but for some other theme named "X". So their support team has provided the person with the following code. So please convert the following code for mystile theme:

```
@media (max-width: 979px){
.x-nav-collapse, .x-nav-collapse.collapse {
overflow: hidden;
height: 0!important;
}
.x-nav-collapse, .x-nav-collapse.collapse.in {
height: auto!important;
}
}
```

And do you think this will solve my problem?

Comment: Did you try asking this in your mystile theme's support forum? There's a high chance your issue might already be solved.

Comment: Can you give us your website link?